# A first order sentence such that the finite spectrum of that sentence is the following subsets of $\mathbb{N}^+$.

Tags: logic, model-theory

I would like to find a language $\mathcal{L}$ and first order sentence $\phi$ of $\mathcal{L}$ so that its finite spectrum is

1. $\{p^n ~:~ n > 0, \text{ p is prime}\}$
2. $\{ p ~:~ p \text{ is prime}\}$

It seems like a large library of mathematical knowledge is needed to even begin consider such questions, and I have to admit mine are thin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For the first problem consider [finite fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field).

The trick for the second problem is to construct a language and sentence for which the finite models look enough like initial segments of the positive integers, or something very similar. One especially elegant approach uses the *something very similar* idea. You’ll want a language $\{+,\times,\le,',2,a,b\}$. Then write down axioms that say that

- $\le$ is a linear order,
- $2$ is the smallest element,
- $b$ is the largest element,
- $x'$ is the immediate successor of $x$ if $x<b$,
- $a<b\land a'=b$,
- $b'=b$,
- $\forall x(x+2)=x''$,
- $\forall x\forall y\big(x+y'=(x+y)'\big)$,
- $\forall x(x\times 2=x+x)$, and
- $\forall x\forall y\big(x\times y'=(x\times y)+x\big)$.

Show that if $2\le n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is (up to isomorphism) exactly one model of these axioms of cardinality $n$, and it’s $\{2,\ldots,n\}$ with the usual ordering and operations, with $a$ interpreted as $n$ and $b$ as $n+1$, and all of the integers greater than $n$ collapsed into the single entity $b$.

Note that an integer $n>1$ is composite iff it’s the product of two smaller integers greater than $1$, so the compositeness (and hence the primality) of $a$ can be expressed in this language.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem consider the theory of fields in the language $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$. It is well known fact that finite fields have $p^n$ elements.

For the second problem, consider the language $\{+,-,\cdot,0,1,<\}$ and the theory $T$ containing the theory of fields with additional axioms:

1. formulas saying that $<$ is irreflexive and transitive (i.e. strict order);
2. $\forall x\,(x+1\neq 0\Rightarrow x<x+1)$.

If $M$ is a finite model of $T$, then $M$ is a field with $p^n$ elements, for some prime $p$. If $M\neq \mathbb F_p$, then $M$ containes an element $a\notin \mathbb F_p$, so $a+i\neq 0$ holds, hence by the axiom 2. $a<a+1<a+2<\ldots <a+p-1<a+p=a$, which contradicts the axiom 1. Therefore $M=\mathbb F_p$, i.e. has $p$ elements.

On the other hand, you can order elements of $\mathbb F_p$ as: $0<1<2<\ldots<p-1$. This shows that $\mathbb F_p$ is a model of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

Both sets and their complements are spectra. Consider the language $\mathcal{L}$ (which contains only predicates and equality) and the $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $A'$ I define in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489715/30229) answer (you will also find how the predicates I use next are defined).

Now, for 1. let $B$ be the $\mathcal{L}$-sentence saying that a prime power is the largest element in our domain:
$$\exists z\,\exists v\,((\neg\exists w\, Rzw)\wedge(\neg\exists x\,\exists y\,(Rxv\wedge Ryv\wedge Qxyv))\wedge(\neg Ov)\wedge\forall x\,((\neg Ox\wedge\exists y\,Qxyz)\Rightarrow\exists w\,Qvwx)).$$

The set of prime powers is the spectrum of $A'\wedge B$, and its complement is the spectrum of $A'\wedge\neg B$.

Now, for 2. let $B$ be the $\mathcal{L}$-sentence saying that a prime number is the largest element in our domanin:
$$\exists z\,((\neg\exists w\, Rzw)\wedge(\neg\exists x\,\exists y\,(Rxz\wedge Ryz\wedge Qxyz))\wedge(\neg Oz)).$$

The set of prime numbers is the spectrum of $A'\wedge B$, and its complement, the set of composite numbers, is the spectrum of $A'\wedge\neg B$.